# MVC 3 and RTL - Issues with IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, right-to-left

I've been working with a very simple ASP.Net MVC3 project to experiment with localization of strings and RTL. I have a view that looks like this:

---

```
@model LocalizationExample.Models.HomeModel

@using Microsoft.License.Ux.Partner.LanguageResources.Order;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>@OrderResource.PageTitle</h2>
<div dir="rtl">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field1) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field1)<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field2) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field2)<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field3) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field3)<br />
</div>
```

---

In FireFox 10 & Chrome 17, this results in three rows of TextBox's with the Labels on the right - all aligned on the right side of the browser.

In IE9, the first two textboxes have the labels to the left and the last textbox has the label to the right - all are aligned on the right side of the browser.

I've tried moving the "dir" up to the body tag and also to the html tag, but I get the same result.  How can I get this to display correctly in IE9?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

They seem to align properly if you nest them inside divs:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field1) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field1)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field2) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field2)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Field3) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field3)
    </div>
</div>
```